# Is there a calendar that I can sync with my phone, without using Google?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

My Google calendar is getting messed up big time. Birth dates are multiplying on my Android phone. Even the dates are changing.

I want a calendar on my PC that I can sync with my Android phone, without using Google. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried resolving the multiplying birth dates? Or the date-changing that's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The table at http://www.syncdroid.net/ is quite comprehensive. If you have Outlook, there are ways to sync your calendar with your device. Always list your device and OS - it helps.